# How to optimize the code to group, sort and apply "diff" to the DataFrame (currently runs very slowly on a small data set)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
utc_timestamp               feed    data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   A       1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   A       5
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   B       6
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   A       10
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   A       11
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   B       11
```

I need to group the data by `feed`, then sort by `utc_timestamp` in ascending order within each group, and finally apply `diff` to data (now `data` contains stacked values and I need to unstack them).

The expected result is the following:

```
utc_timestamp               feed    data
2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00   A       1
2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00   A       4
2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00   A       5
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   A       1
2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00   B       6
2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00   B       5
```

It's important that `diff` should be applied independently within each group, as shown in the result.

This is my current solution:

```
gb = df.groupby(['feed', 'utc_timestamp'])
df_subset = gb.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['utc_timestamp'])).shift(fill_value=0)
df_subset.head()
```

But it takes a very long time to execute (though the DataFrame only contains 30K records).

How can I optimize this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` should be avoided since you loose vectorization across groups. Instead, sort the values first, then groupby:

```
df['data'] -= (df.sort_values('utc_timestamp')
                 .groupby('feed')['data'].shift(fill_value=0)
              )
```

Output:

```
               utc_timestamp feed  data
0  2015-10-13 11:00:00+00:00    A     1
1  2015-10-13 12:00:00+00:00    A     4
2  2015-10-13 13:00:00+00:00    B     6
3  2015-10-13 14:00:00+00:00    A     5
4  2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00    A     1
5  2015-10-13 15:00:00+00:00    B     5
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the meaning of `-=`?

Comment: in-place subtraction, similar to `x = x - 3`, we can use `x -= 3`.

Comment: Ok, do I understand correctly that I should substitute `df["data"]` by `df_new` if I want to have the result in a new DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, given that `df_new = df.copy()`. Or better yet `df_new = df.sort_values(['utc_timestamp', 'feed'])`. And you can replace `df` by `df_new` in the command above and forget about `sort_values`.

Comment: Ok, I used `df.sort_values(['feed','utc_timestamp'])`, i.e. `feed` first, because the data should be grouped by `feed`, not by `utc_timestamp`.